# managing openvz on multiple servers

Tags: cluster, virtualization, openvz

I have 3 (quad core each) servers that I'm going to run a small 10 server virtual cluster on.  I'm using openvz. xen and kvm aren't options.

My current plan is to have a script that resides on each of the servers that I give a unique id, hostname, ip, and the script will automatically start the VE and bootstrap puppet to automatically set things up.

Is this how you would bootstrap a virtual cluster?  Or are there management tools / methods to help with this kind of thing (many VEs on many physical servers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For openvz management the coolest solution I tried on around 20 machines was Proxmox VE (http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Main_Page) and it was damn nice. You can connect to each server and see the whole node/vm topology , provision resources and so on. I don't know how it scales when run on a larger number of physical nodes tough.
Tools like Puppet or CFEngine or Chef or similar are very good at doing everything :) But if you need something quick and dirty to manage your VMs, Proxmox is great. In our shop we consider physical servers dumb aka they don't do anything intelligent besides hosting virtual machines. We deploy them remotely using network based install from some standard system images and then spend most of our working hours operating VMs.